# Match word of specific length

Tags: regex, awk

How do I match a word of a specific length, let's say, five?

Given the input file `temp` of text:

```
1) ci sono quattro mele
2) sentiamoci il 16 ottobre 2018
3) decidiamo il 17 ottabre 2017
4) Manipolo di eroi
5) 17 mele
6) 18 ott 2020
7) una mela e mezza
8) 2 mele
```

If i do:

```
awk '/[[:lower:]]{5}/ {print}' temp
```

I would expect as output the sentence `7)`, because is the only one with a word of length `5` (`mezza`). Actually, it returns every line with a word of length equal or superior than `5`.

This behavior is not compatible with any source of information I consulted:

- [Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)
- [Official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators)

The construct `{n}` should match exactly `n` times. At this point, I am afraid I am missing something obvious.

Comment: It's probably possible to find a better duplicate; this is definitely a common FAQ.

Comment: You need word boundaries. That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's matching because it found a string of 5 lowercase letters within the string of longer length. You need to adapt your regex so that the "word" match is surrounded by white space. Don't forget to also address the start/end of the string in the "word" boundary.

Comment: So `(^|[[:space:]])[[:lower:]]{5}([[:space:]]|$)` or possibly also inclule numbers, punctuation, and/or uppercase in the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The construct {n} **does** match exactly n times, what you're missing is that a word with 7 letters has 5 letters within it and so matches {5}. You need to specify what can or can't precede and succeed those 5 letters too to avoid a partial match like that.

With GNU awk for word boundaries `\<` and `\>` and `\w` for word-constituent characters:

```
$ awk '/\<\w{5}\>/' file
7) una mela e mezza
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '/(^|[^[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]{5}([^[:alpha:]]|$)/' file
7) una mela e mezza
```

Those and any other solution will obviously depend on what you mean by a "word".

Answer (score 1):

if it's always surrounded by spaces you can do the following
`[[:lower:]]{5}\s+` or `\s+[[:lower:]]{5}\s+`
(depending what you want to do)

Comment: Awk doesn't support `\s` in any version I'm familiar with.

Comment: @tripleee GNU awk does. That's the only one AFAIK but of course GNU awk also supports word boundaries which might be the more appropriate construct in this case. njank - the `+`s in your regexp are doing nothing useful you could just remove them.

Answer (score 1):

since you have the full functionality of `awk`, why restrict yourself to regex matching?

```
$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' 'length($0)==5' file

mezza
```

Comment: `RS='[[:space:]]+'` would include blanks and newlines and tabs, etc. so, for example, it wouldn't fail if a file contained 5 contiguous tabs. It would still fail (presumably) if the file contained a 5-digit number or `no;on`, etc. but it all depends what the OP means by a "word". For all we know `no;on` and `12345` are both "word"s to the OP.

Comment: yes, right; I thought this use of `RS` suggests adding other word delimiter chars (`\t`, `;` etc) as well.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, idk. Using `RS='[[:alpha:]]+'` with `length(RT)==5` might be reasonable too (since multi-char RS requires GNU awk you have RT available). The other problem with this though is that the OP wants the whole line output: `I would expect as output the sentence 7), because is the only one with a word of length 5` and you can't do that if you've lost the line endings.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Vu5oea/1/)

`(?<![[:lower:]])[[:lower:]]{5}(?![[:lower:]])`

- look for 5 lower
- use negative lookahed&behind to get boundaries

**Unix example**

```
 grep -P '(?<![[:lower:]])[[:lower:]]{5}(?![[:lower:]])' temp
```

**Result**

```
7) una mela e mezza
```

**Perl example** (same output) - ty @Ed Morton

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<![[:lower:]])[[:lower:]]{5}(?![[:lower:]])/' temp
```

Comment: @EdMorton I edited the answer to give a `grep` solution. Or am I mistaken that `grep` is a "standard UNIX tool"?

Comment: It is better but `grep -P` is only available in a non-standard, GNU-only version of grep and even [the man page for it](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) says "This is highly experimental," and there have been reports of it core dumping. `cat file | grep 'regexp'` is a [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html), btw - use `grep 'regexp' file` instead.

Comment: @EdMorton didnt know that, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. People do use `grep -P` but I don't know why since if you can use GNU grep then you're not restricted to only using POSIX tools and then you can use perl and not have the "highly experimental" issue. You also don't **need** to use PCREs, you can always express what you want with other EREs that standard tools (e.g. grep/sed/awk) do understand. Personally if the person who develops a tool tells me it's "highly experimental" and I don't **need** to use it then that's good enough for me to stay away!

Comment: @EdMorton added a perl example :) - i hope this isnt highly experimental aswell :D

Comment: Nope and it's no more non-standard than `grep -P`.